# How to get gridview values that was changed by javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I am in problem. I need to get gridview values that was changed by javascript.

my GV is:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridViewImageList" CssClass="GridView" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridViewHeader" RowStyle-CssClass="GridViewRow" FooterStyle-CssClass="GridViewFooter"  runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridViewImageList_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDeleting="GridViewImageList_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="GridViewImageList_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridViewImageList_RowUpdating" OnRowDataBound="GridViewImageList_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="false" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image Name" Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelImageName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ImageName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageThumbURL") %>' runat="server" Height="75" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Size">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListPhotoSize" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Number of Copy">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxNumber" runat="server"  MaxLength="3" Width="20px" Text='<%# Eval("Number") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

by inputting below textbox:

and js function:

```
    function updateAllTextbox(obj, item) {
        var totalRows = parseInt('<%= GridViewImageList.Rows.Count %>');
        var gvAllControl = document.getElementById('<%= GridViewImageList.ClientID %>');
        var gvItemControls = "";
        var gvHeaderControl = "";
        if (item == "number")
        {
            gvItemControls = "TextBoxNumber";
            gvHeaderControl = document.getElementById("textBoxNumberAll");
        }

        //get an array of input types in the gridview
        var inputTypes = gvAllControl.getElementsByTagName("input");

        for (var i = 0; i < inputTypes.length; i++) {
            //if the input type is a checkbox and the id of it is what we set above
            //then check or uncheck according to the main checkbox in the header template            
            if (inputTypes[i].type == 'text' && inputTypes[i].id.indexOf(gvItemControls, 0) >= 0)
                inputTypes[i].value = obj.value;


        }

    }
```

i am changing values of TextBoxNumber field off all rows.

But when i am reading values from Gridview, it is not showing the changed value. please help

Answer (score 0):

finally i got the main point.
It was nothing but the binding of gridview in page load event without Ispostback property.
Every time when u r firing any event first that page load event will fire just bind ur gridview using

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
   bindgrid();
}
```